# Sublime Text 2 file search not working?

Tags: python, directory, sublime-text

Sublime Text 2 has an extremely handy feature to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and be able to fuzzy search for files in a given specified directory.

This worked well on Windows, but on Ubuntu it doesn't recognise the sub directories of my `/var/www/` folder, just the files, meaning I can't search through my development server easily. I tried starting Sublime with sudo but that didn't help. Any thoughts?

Comment: It works fine on Ubuntu. How did you start sublime? What does your project look like? Post a screenshot of sidebar maybe. Have you tried `sublime-text /var/www`?

Comment: Ah. Your suggestion worked. Still learning the ropes, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to search files via Sublime Text 2, you have to have them opened as a project.

The easiest way to accomplish so is to start sublime from the terminal using

```
sublime-text /path/to/directory
```